# Problems with Rails 4 app into Bluehost

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I'm facing some problems launching my rails app hosted on bluehost.

I think that the problem is the passenger version interacting with the rails 4 app but I'm not sure.

When I launch my app I get this trace:

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
These are the possible causes:
There may be a syntax error in the application's code. Please check for such errors and fix them.
A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
The application may not be properly configured. Please check whether all configuration files are written correctly, fix any incorrect configurations, and restart this application.
A service that the application relies on (such as the database server or the Ferret search engine server) may not have been started. Please start that service.
Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.
Error message:
Could not initialize MySQL client library
Exception class:
RuntimeError
Application root:
/home5/barracam/rails_apps/admin/admin
Backtrace:
#   File    Line    Location
0   /home5/barracam/ruby/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2.rb  31  in `require'
1   /home5/barracam/ruby/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2.rb  31  in `'
2   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    72  in `require'
3   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    72  in `block (2 levels) in require'
4   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    70  in `each'
5   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    70  in `block in require'
6   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    59  in `each'
7   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    59  in `require'
8   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb    132 in `require'
9   /home5/barracam/rails_apps/admin/admin/config/application.rb    7   in `'
10  /home5/barracam/rails_apps/admin/admin/config/environment.rb    2   in `require'
11  /home5/barracam/rails_apps/admin/admin/config/environment.rb    2   in `'
12  config.ru   3   in `require'
13  config.ru   3   in `block in'
14  /home5/barracam/ruby/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb   55  in `instance_eval'
15  /home5/barracam/ruby/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb   55  in `initialize'
16  config.ru   1   in `new'
17  config.ru   1   in `'
18  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  225 in `eval'
19  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  225 in `load_rack_app'
20  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  157 in `block in initialize_server'
21  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 563 in `report_app_init_status'
22  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  154 in `initialize_server'
23  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   204 in `start_synchronously'
24  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   180 in `start'
25  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  129 in `start'
26  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 253 in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
27  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    132 in `lookup_or_add'
28  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 246 in `block in spawn_rack_application'
29  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    82  in `block in synchronize'
30      prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
31  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    79  in `synchronize'
32  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 244 in `spawn_rack_application'
33  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 137 in `spawn_application'
34  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 275 in `handle_spawn_application'
35  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357 in `server_main_loop'
36  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   206 in `start_synchronously'
37  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server  99  in `'
Powered by Phusion Passenger, mod_rails / mod_rack for Apache and Nginx.
```

I tried to run a rails 3 app and all works fine. What do you think about the problem?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but a question: any reason not to use Heroku or other app-friendly deploy? Bluehost, I found can really burn up a lot of your time trying to get app deployed there.

Comment: Some not functional requirements. The idea is to have all into the client bluehost server. But maybe you're right, a domain pointing to a Heroku app seems to be the best solution to this problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing.

Comment: One more thing.  I understand the goal of having all work on one host, I'm looking at Webfaction hosting to migrate all my work to. They claim to be app friendly, yet are reasonably priced.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, so after a lot of research, and trial and error.... I locked my mysql2 gem at version 3.0.16, and set up my database.yml like so:

```
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
database: store
username: root
password: 
host: localhost
reconnect: true
port: 3306
```

My app is running rails on 4.20, and works fine now.
(although it still has sporadic trouble connecting to the mysql db? maybe the bluest server gets overloaded? there is no real pattern, and it doesn't happen all that often.

Comment: I will give it a try, but know my app is running with a postgreSQL db without problems.

Comment: @halbano I ended up migrating to postgresql too. mysql is a nightmare on bluehost. the server keeps being shut down every 10mins or so... I have no such problems using postgresql anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the database.yml

Use `mysql` instead `mysql2` adapter