# Ruby Could not initialize MySQL client library

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I updated my ruby on Bluehost following the guide below.
http://www.haydonryan.com/installing-ruby-2-1-1p76-and-rails-4-0-4-on-bluehost/
http://www.haydonryan.com/rails-4-passenger-and-bluehost-with-a-cameo-from-wordpress/

Then I installed redmine using the guide from bluehost.
If I run rails s through ssh, I get

> => Booting WEBrick
>       => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on localhost 3000
>       => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>       => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>       [2015-10-13 06:45:51] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
>       [2015-10-13 06:45:51] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
>       [2015-10-13 06:45:51] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=19685 port=3000

However, if I open the url from my browser, I get the error message below. What could be causing this?

> Error message: Could not initialize MySQL client library   Exception
>   class: RuntimeError   Application root: /home/user/rails_apps/redmine 
>   Backtrace:
>       # File Line Location
>       0 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb
>   274 in require
>       1 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb
>   274 in block in require
>       2 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb
>   240 in load_dependency
>       3 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb
>   274 in require
>       4 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2.rb 31 in
>       5 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb 76 in require
>       6 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb 76 in block (2 levels) in require
>       7 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb 72 in each
>       8 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb 72 in block in require
>       9 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb 61 in each
>       10 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb 61 in require
>       11 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb 134 in require
>       12 /home5/user/rails_apps/redmine/config/application.rb 5 in
>       13 /home5/user/rails_apps/redmine/config/environment.rb 2 in require
>       14 /home5/user/rails_apps/redmine/config/environment.rb 2 in
>       15 config.ru 3 in require
>       16 config.ru 3 in block in
>       17 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb 55 in instance_eval
>       18 /home/user/ruby/gems/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb 55 in initialize
>       19 config.ru 1 in new
>       20 config.ru 1 in
>       21 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb
>   225 in eval
>       22 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb
>   225 in load_rack_app
>       23 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb
>   157 in block in initialize_server
>       24 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 563 in report_app_init_status
>       25 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb
>   154 in initialize_server
>       26 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb
>   204 in start_synchronously
>       27 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb
>   180 in start
>       28 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb
>   129 in start
>       29 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
>   253 in block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application
>       30 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb
>   132 in lookup_or_add
>       31 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
>   246 in block in spawn_rack_application
>       32 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb
>   82 in block in synchronize
>       33 prelude> 10:in synchronize
>       34 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb
>   79 in synchronize
>       35 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
>   244 in spawn_rack_application
>       36 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
>   137 in spawn_application
>       37 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
>   275 in handle_spawn_application
>       38 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb
>   357 in server_main_loop
>       39 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb
>   206 in start_synchronously
>       40 /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server 99
>   in

Comment: Same issue here, tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884115/problems-with-rails-4-app-into-bluehost but didn't work